# how to prevent jbuilder (rails) from calling database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, performance

I have a situation involving a controller and a [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) view. The controller grabs a bunch of records and updates them. The view renders the updated books in JSON using jbuilder.

**app/controllers/books_controller.rb**

```
def change_book_attributes
    @books = Book.where(...)
    @books.update_all(...)
    #@books.reload
end
```

**app/views/books/change_book_attributes.json.jbuilder**

```
json.seats @books, :id, :title, :state
```

The situation is that when I update multiple books simultaneously I get one SQL UPDATE statement (as expected) and multiple SQL SELECT statements (unexpected - one for each book!), whereas I would prefer having just one SELECT statement (such as one issued by `@books.reload` - I commented it out above because it is currently pointless due to the fact that jbuilder seems to issue a SELECT statement for each book).

If I temporarily remove the single line inside the jbuilder file, then there is no `SELECT` issued - this tells me that it is jbuilder that is issuing those SELECT statements (one for each book).

Question: How can jbuilder be forced to use the existing @books (possibly updated with `@books.reload` in the controller)?

(If I change 100 books, I don't want 100 SELECT statements - I want just one.)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this. We are having a very similar problem.

Comment: Sorry, no... but I also stopped searching not long after posting this question; perhaps you will have better luck now that 1 year and 9 months have passed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing `json.seats @books, :id, :title, :state`   to `Json.extract! @books, :id, :title, :state`  and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried what you suggested, and have bad news and possibly good news. The bad news is that the output produced the error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'id' for #<Book::ActiveRecord_Relation:...`. The possibly good news is that as a test I changed the last lines of the controller method to `@books.reload; @books = @books.first` so as to give it an object that it *can* find `id` in (as opposed to a collection of objects)... now the question is how can jbuilder be made to cycle over each member of the `@books` ActiveRecord_Relation?

Comment: I also tried [`json.array!`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/jbuilder/Jbuilder:array!) and although it worked in terms of cycling over each member of `@books`, it still called the database for each. How can it be made to just use what it's given and not look up each one?